# Displaying search status when searching with ack within Vim

Tags: search, vim, status, ack

Is there a way to display the search status, when searching with ack within vim? Maybe percentage?

Comment: what do you mean by search status. do you want a kind of progress bar ?

Comment: Something like:

'Searching.... [67%]'

Would be nice.

Comment: Ack itself (and therefore Ack.vim) doesn't provide such a mechanism so you might need some third party tool. I just tried `pv` but it doesn't seem to work with Ack.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is something like that. Have you tried the plugin [Ack.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2572)? It has a nice integration with Vim.